# Notification for review of selected/favorite tags

Tags: discussion, tags, review, notifications

There are some times when the review queue is getting long. So is there a possibility for having some kind of notification delivered in inbox regarding the pending reviews (ONLY WHEN VOLUNTARILY CHOSEN) maybe using profile option.

Also as a developer I would like if there is an option for getting notification for specific tags pending for review.

Is it somehow possible?

Comment: I was thinking about that myself the other day, it would be nice if I could review based on a tag.

Comment: @Mike yes it would be great if that was possible. It is good if we can review posts that we have experience in and get notifications on that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the queue is *long*, I don't see how adding notifications on to this would make the problem  better... I can understand notifications for queues on quiet sites (still, notifications are meant to be personal or for important sitewide announcements--I doubt this would be implemented)

However, you *can* filter posts in a review queue:

[image]